# Generate graph for multiple data in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Apache 2 web-server to display " patient's " data stored in MySQL database. This data stored in columns named : "Temperature , Pulse , Motion" and there is column for the time in which the data arrived the database called "current_time".
I have displayed this data into a html table that display the latest records and the Average each time.

Now I have to display this data into a graph that must be generated each time a new data arrive to database. Anyone has any idea how can I implement this ?

Please help me ..

Answer (score 0):

You don't generate graph in PHP. You should do this in JS, there is a lot of free libraries to generate graphs.

List of 15 libraries: http://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/

You should generate data in php (display or save it as for example JSON) and then generate graph using this JSON data.

Comment: Thank you I'll check them,which one you recommend more? and if you can give me more details please how to save data as JSON ?

Comment: I have used a Morris.js in few projects, and it worked very well ([http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/)). Read about passing arrays to JSON: ([http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever rely on the user having javascript enabled for anything. The graphs that you need can be made with PHP:

http://jpgraph.net/

If the user has javascript enabled then you could perhaps use ajax to grab a new copy of the graph of any updates are made to the data